# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open' Python 3.4 with robobrowser

Tags: python-3.x, robobrowser

So, as a replacement for mechanize because Visual Studio "needs" python 3.4, and mechanize isn't compatible with 3.4, I found "robobrowser" as a replacement, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out why browser.open returns "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'"

```
import re
from robobrowser import browser
import time
br = browser
br.open("Website")
br.select_form(name="game-pin-input")
print ("Enter the game pin")
response = br.submit()
time.sleep(3)
```

Any suggestions, or replacements?

Edit: The Documentation can be found here, and "open" is valid.
https://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-robobrowser.browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `browser` is a module; according to [the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robobrowser), you wanted `RoboBrowser`, and you need to construct an instance before `open`-ing anything. To roughly match your code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

# Browse to Genius
br = RoboBrowser(history=True)  # No idea if history matters
br.open("Website")
```

I'm guessing `robobrowser.browser` is some implementation internal module that is importable, but not at all what you wanted.

**Update**: According to [your own docs link](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#robobrowser.browser.RoboBrowser), `robobrowser.browser` is just a module, and `RoboBrowser` is the class you needed, confirming my earlier statement (`RoboBrowser` is probably exposed on `robobrowser` itself for convenience).